# Can't seem to get rid of unwanted tags returned from API

Tags: php, html-entities, strip-tags

I need to get rid of all the HTML tags in a description that gets returned from the Petfinder API, but I can't seem to figure out how.

`$data['description']` holds the returned description. What I can see in the source file is something like this...

```
<div>some text that gets returned</div>
```

I've tried using `strip_tags`, Ive tried it with `html_entity_decode`, but the tags won't go away!

I need to strip the tags so that I can truncate the description..

Anyone have any ideas?

```
$data['description'] = (string)$pet->description;

$description = $data['description'];
$description = htmlentities($description);
$description = html_entity_decode($description);
$description = strip_tags($description);

$description = substr($data['description'],0,300);
$description = substr($description,0,strrpos($description,' '));
$description = $description."...";

echo "<span style='text-align: justify; margin: 10px 0px;'>".$description."</span>";
```

Comment: show the description text..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the original input again half-way your processing:

```
$description = $data['description'];
$description = htmlentities($description);
$description = html_entity_decode($description);
$description = strip_tags($description);

$description = substr($data['description'],0,300);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ All previous changes undone!
$description = substr($description,0,strrpos($description,' '));
$description = $description."...";
```

Apart from that, @redreggae is right, you only need `strip_tags`.

Comment: it's always the simplest things... Thanks to you and thanks to @redreggae!

Answer (score 2):

the problem is you first run `htmlentities`.
After this `strip_tags` can't work anymore.

Simply do:

```
$test = '<div>some text that gets returned</div>';
echo strip_tags($test);
```

The hardcore way:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<div>some text that gets returned</div>');
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
$content = $items->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $content;
```

Comment: that isn't working. I started with just strip_tags and it didn't do anything, so I added html_entity_decode thinking maybe the tags were htmlentities. That didn't work, so I added htmlentities, and that doesn't work.